# Solve websocket performance issue with Astro Framework

Tags: javascript, websocket, astrojs

I started a project with the Astro Framework because is supposed to have very good performance but this happened

[Website has very bad performance because of websockets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/31SO9.png)

Problem is I am kind of new so I don't know nothing about websockets, I never added some kind of websocket configuration or something like that

And this is what appears in the network tab:
[It says there is some file called client.ts that is calling that websocket, and that file is in the vite configuration, so I don't understand what is happening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tXGOj.png)

I tried to delete the client.ts file to stop it from calling the websocket but It could break the entire app so I don't know what to do

Comment: It looks like you're running the app in development mode. Vite (which powers Astro) uses websockets to enable features like reloading the page when you save a file during development. You can build the project with `npm run build` (see more about [building your site](https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/deploy/#building-your-site-locally) and [deploying](https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/deploy/#quick-deploy-options) it to hosting providers)